# Using SSH authentication configurations for xrdp

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, authentication, xrdp, pam

I have a server where its `ssh` is configured to allow some users and groups from AD, and the configuration is done in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`.

However, this configuration is only applied to `ssh`, and if someone is trying to access the server through RDP, they can access it, and it absolutely makes sense, because the authentication is configured to be done only for SSH not for XRDP. Now I want a way to apply these configurations also to the xrdp, which is running on the server, so that if someone trying to access via XRDP, they should go through the same authentication process as someone goes while trying to ssh.

Comment: Well, there are a couple of main files in /etc/pam.d/ including comm-auth, I made the configs in this file, and seems to be working, but not sure if that is the way I should do it.

Answer (score 0):

it's good what you did,
but the usually more secure
approach would be tunneling
the xrdp connection over ssh.

[you may find the detailed process here](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=14965)